# HTML Contact Form without using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, contact-form

I am creating a contact form using HTML but I am putting the code as

```
<form method="post" name="contactform" id="contactform" action="mailto:contact@xyzmail.com" enctype="text/plain">
```

but on clicking the submit button, it is opening operating system Windows 8 email editor to send mail, while I want to directly send mail on 'Submit' button click.

Comment: Please add your code to your question.

Comment: without PHP, then why tag the quesiton with PHP?

Comment: If you do not want to use OS mail app, and not a server-side program, how will you send the mail ? Do you have any SMTP ?